# Partition of Bill no in last and previous by customer id based on date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, partition-by

I am trying to part bill no in latest and previous based on date by customer id.

this is the data :

[image]
this data contains bill number along with its start and end date by customer

output should be like this :

[image]

output should be into latest and previous bill number by customer id (please check image)

```
select a.customerid, a.start_date,a.end_date,a.bill_number
from emp_bills a
join emp_bills b
on a.customerid= b.customerid
group by customerid;
```

Comment: Provide more info. What data is inside table or their relation.

Comment: this data contains bill number along with its start and end date by customer, output should be into latest and previous bill number by customer id (please check image)

Comment: One last thing, latest bill is a bill who's start_date is highest and previous bill is who's start_date is second highest

Comment: i am not quire sure bro, this is google interview Question and i just got rejected :/ because of this question. question was not pretty clearly communicated.

Comment: I think the query itself is easy, but latest bill can be anything, example - start_date is highest or end_date is highest. If you wanna still solve this assume anything and give it a shot. Hard part will be to find second largest I guess.

Comment: i have tried using case it didn't work, tried using self join still no help:/

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an interview question I think it is fair to assume that each row (for a given user) will have a different (and incremental) start date.
In the real world this will often not be the case and proper steps to ensure data quality should be taken, but let's go with the happy case.

```
WITH prep_step AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
  customer_ID,
  LAST_VALUE(Bill_number) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY start_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS latest_bill,
  LAST_VALUE(Bill_number) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY start_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS second_latest_bill_candidate
FROM emp_bills
)

SELECT
  customer_id,
  latest_bill,
  MAX(second_latest_bill_candidate) AS second_latest_bill
FROM prep_step
GROUP BY 
  customer_id,
  latest_bill
```

Comment: tried however it not working. thank you for the contribution tho

Comment: Would you mind sharing the error message?